# Square Triangles

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

A positive integer **x** is a square triangle number iff there are two different positive integers, **y** and **z**, which are smaller than **x** such that all of the sums

**x + y**

**x + z**

**y + z**

are perfect squares.

For example 30 is a square triangle number because

**30 + 6 = 6<sup>2</sup>**

**30 + 19 = 7<sup>2</sup>**

**6 + 19 = 5<sup>2</sup>**

---

Your task is to write some code that takes a positive integer as input and determines whether or not it is a square triangle number.  You should output one of two distinct values, one if the input is a square triangle number and the other otherwise.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

### Testcases

Here are all of the square triangle numbers under 1000

```
30,44,47,48,60,66,69,70,78,86,90,92,94,95,96,98,108,113,116,118,120,122,124,125,126,132,138,142,147,150,152,154,156,157,158,159,160,165,170,176,180,182,185,186,188,190,192,194,195,196,197,198,200,207,212,214,216,218,221,222,224,227,230,232,234,236,237,238,239,240,246,248,253,258,260,264,266,267,268,270,273,274,275,276,278,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,290,296,298,302,303,306,308,310,312,314,317,318,320,322,323,324,326,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,338,340,344,347,350,351,352,356,357,360,362,364,368,370,371,372,374,376,377,378,380,382,384,385,386,387,388,389,390,392,394,396,402,405,408,410,413,414,415,418,420,422,423,424,426,429,430,432,434,435,436,438,440,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,449,452,456,458,462,464,466,467,468,470,472,476,477,479,480,482,484,485,488,490,491,492,494,496,497,498,500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,512,515,516,518,522,523,524,527,528,530,533,536,538,540,542,543,546,548,549,550,551,552,554,557,558,560,562,563,564,566,568,569,570,571,572,573,574,575,576,578,579,582,585,588,590,592,593,594,598,600,602,603,604,605,606,608,610,612,613,614,615,616,618,620,621,623,624,626,627,628,630,632,633,634,636,638,639,640,641,642,643,644,645,646,650,652,656,657,658,659,660,662,666,667,668,670,672,674,677,678,680,682,683,686,687,689,690,692,694,695,696,698,700,701,702,704,706,707,708,709,710,711,712,713,714,715,716,717,718,719,720,722,723,726,728,730,734,737,739,740,742,744,745,746,750,752,755,756,758,760,762,764,765,767,768,770,772,773,774,776,778,779,780,782,783,784,785,786,788,789,790,791,792,793,794,795,796,797,798,800,802,803,804,805,810,812,814,816,817,818,819,820,822,825,826,827,828,829,830,832,833,834,836,837,838,840,842,846,847,848,849,850,851,852,854,855,856,858,860,861,862,863,864,866,867,868,869,870,871,872,873,874,875,876,877,878,879,880,882,884,888,890,891,893,896,897,898,902,903,904,905,908,912,913,914,915,916,918,920,923,924,926,927,928,929,931,932,933,935,936,938,940,941,942,944,946,947,948,950,952,953,954,955,956,957,958,959,960,961,962,963,964,965,966,967,968,970,972,974,976,978,980,981,984,986,987,988,992,993,995,996,998
```

[OEIS A242445](http://oeis.org/A242445)

Comment: This is [OEIS A242445](https://oeis.org/A242445).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks! I probably should have checked the OEIS first.  I'll add that to the body to make it more searchable.

Comment: For clarification purposes, *"...iff there are two different positive integers, y and z, which are smaller than x..."*  means that `y < x` and `z < x` or that `y+z < x`?

Comment: @J.Sallé The former

Comment: Here test case with input and output are absent

Comment: What does it mean:"You should output one of two distinct values, one if the input is a square triangle number and the other otherwise."? Perhaps it has to return true false...

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 62 bytes

```hs
f x|l<-(^2)<$>[1..x]=or[b>x|c<-l,b<-l,a<-l,a-x+b-x==c,c<b,b<a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3LCoMwEEV/ZRAXkUykUSktJH5Bu@rSWkikxdL4QC2dhf@eGjeHwz2L25r583TO@xfQ6pRgjyxRcVnJNKVaD1NlS1obJRzaALNDELeCtG6wUXYLpvadefcaOjNegd0JRAnjd7kt06WHGOZ2@AEB5xCFEgXbN7a9JglU8og55gcsCpQZnk@1/wM)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
R²_fṖŒcS€Æ²Ẹ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//UsKyX2bhuZbFkmNT4oKsw4bCsuG6uP8xMDAww4fDkGZq4oCdLP8)

#### How it works

```
R²_fṖŒcS€Æ²Ẹ  Main link. Argument: x

R             Range; yield [1, 2, ..., x].
 ²            Square; yield [1², 2², ..., x²].
  _           Subtract; yield [1²-x, 2²-x, ..., x²-x].
    Ṗ         Pop; yield [1, 2, ..., x-1].
   f          Filter; keep those values of n²-x that lie between 1 and x-1.
              This list contains all integers n such that n+x is a perfect square.
              We'll try to find suitable values for y and z from this list.
     Œc       Yield all 2-combinations [y, z] of these integers.
       S€     Take the sum of each pair.
         Æ²   Test each resulting integer for squareness.
           Ẹ  Any; check is the resulting array contains a 1.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>93</s> <s>87</s> 86 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Dennis</sup>

```python
lambda n:{0}in[{m**.5%1for m in[x+y,n+x,n+y]}for x in range(1,n)for y in range(1+x,n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcoxCoQwEEDR3lNMIxiVJQo2AU@iFll2owNmlGCRIDn7mHQWv3n8M1zbQT2bceZd2@9PA6lbRqTptnX9GcrOHA4sJPBNaKnxqbDErD4pOE3rv@paEpnCi/IqFs6ML5ZSqALQgKlQqNMhXYDMDw)

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 19 bytes

```
~hṪ>₁ℕ₁ᵐ≜¬{⊇Ċ+¬~^₂}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vy7j4c5Vdo@aGh@1TAWSD7dOeNQ559Ca6kdd7Ue6tA@tqYt71NRU@/@/oaHZfwA)

Also 19 bytes: `~hṪ>₁ℕ₁ᵐ≜{⊇Ċ+}ᶠ~^₂ᵐ`

#### Explanation

```
~hṪ                    Ṫ = [Input, A, B]
  Ṫ>₁                  Ṫ is strictly decreasing (i.e. Input > A > B)
  Ṫ  ℕ₁ᵐ               All members of Ṫ are in [1, +∞)
  Ṫ     ≜              Assign values to A and B that fit those constraints
  Ṫ      ¬{       }    It is impossible for Ṫ…
           ⊇Ċ            …that one of its 2-elements subset…
            Ċ+           …does not sum…
              ¬~^₂       …to a square
```

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 150 bytes

```powershell
param($x)filter f($a,$b){($c=[math]::Sqrt($a+$b))-eq[math]::Floor($c)}1..($i=$x-1)|%{$y=$_;1..$i|%{$o+=+($y-ne$_)*(f $x $y)*(f $x $_)*(f $y $_)}};!!$o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcrRCoIwAIXhV5lwgi2bJN0pu@0FuoyQFRMH0@ka5DCffU2o7v7zcUb7Uu7ZKWNiHKWTPcXMWm28cqSlkAfc2ULxENde@u5WVZfJ@eR5csbV9OOzsdalH1vLoqDQAjMv2Xu3IAg0dULobdlc5BSBDwoN29OWYCYI//pa2Gpd6yyDjTGejh8) or [Verify some test cases](https://tio.run/##PczRCoIwFAbge59iyQm21kRvlXXZC3QZIUsmCurmMnLYnn3NKO/@8/H/R6uXNI9Gdp2vn0M1tWpANQZxhDtZMFT82oupueX5ZTRTcBqcMDn@@dwpZUKPuGjb68VrYUSPYSageBplSYKh5TCzjLz3C1gOZREQ2vVSlFMMlg0SSnLANYIZgd3Sz@yanCt2O1DerS@zNA3zGErETihGFGH97fgP)

Takes input `$x`. Establishes a `filter` (here equivalent to a function) on two inputs `$a,$b`, which returns a Boolean true iff the `[math]::sqrt` of `$a+$b` is `-eq`ual to the `Floor` of that square root (i.e., it's an integer square root).

The rest of it is the meat of the program. We double-for loop up from `1` to `$x-1`. Each iteration, we check whether `$y` is `-n`ot`e`qual to `$_` (i.e., $z), and whether the function is true for all combinations of `$x`, `$y` and `$_`. If it is, `$o` is incremented by one (which makes it non-zero).

Finally, at the end, we double-Boolean-negate `$o`, which turns `0` into `False` and non-zero into `True`. That's left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES7), <s>75</s> 71 bytes

```js
f=
n=>(g=i=>i?--j?[n+i,i+j,j+n].some(e=>e**.5%1)?g(i):1:g(j=i-1):0)(j=n-1)
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.textContent=f(+this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Comment: Seems like you ninja'd me by 2 minutes. :) Ours answers are very close, so shall I delete mine?

Comment: @Arnauld No, I'm sure you arrived at your solution independently.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>75</s> 69 bytes

```hs
f x=or[all(`elem`map(^2)[1..x])[x+y,x+z,y+z]|y<-[1..x-1],z<-[1..y-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrBCoMwEER/ZY8JWcVUWyjol4QUc4hUutmK7SEJ/nsM7WGYx5t5us/LE5WyQJzeu3FEYvbkwxzcJh4XaXTbRitNVAmjyphUtkcam59vtMX851TZluBWnrZ95a8RjAuwPLjufYcwDAi32rqm1wjXe/2f)

Could probably be improved if someone knows a shorter way to test if a number is square. I'm pretty sure using `sqrt` ends up being longer because `floor` turns the result into an integral type so you need to put `fromIntegral` in somewhere before you can compare to the original.

EDIT: Thanks @Wheat Wizard for taking off 6 bytes!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
Lns-IL¨Ãæ2ù€OÅ²O0›
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/8wNWFiMWX//0xucy1JTMKow4PDpjLDueKCrE/DhcKyTzDigLr//zE4)

Thanks to [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna) for  <s>-3</s>  -1 byte <s>and a fix</s>!

Comment: You don't need the 2 `€`'s as both `n` and `O` vectorizes. This also doesn't work as the final 2 bytes will return true for any list with at least 1 value, even if only contains false values. This can be fixed (and shortened) by using `Z` instead.

Comment: @Emigna Thank you! (BTW I did need `€O` and that’s why the previous approach *did work* with `\`º`)

Comment: It didn't work though. Check for example `45`, that should return false.

Comment: Um huh, ok. Anyway, updated now. Thanks

Comment: @Sanchises Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 79 bytes

```r
function(x){s=(1:x)^2
S=outer(y<-(z=s-x)[z>0&z<x],y,"+")
diag(S)=0
any(S%in%s)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCs7rYVsPQqkIzzogr2Da/tCS1SKPSRlejyrZYt0IzusrOQK3KpiJWp1JHSVtJkyslMzFdI1jT1oArMa9SI1g1M0@1WLP2f3FiQUFOJdAcExOdNM3/AA)

computes all the values of `y,z` with `y<-(z=s-x)[z>0&z<x]`, then computes all their sums with `outer(y,y,"+")`. This yields a square matrix where off-diagonal entries are potentially squares, as `y==z` only if they are on the diagonal. Hence, `diag(S)=0` sets the diagonals to zero, which are not perfect squares, and we test to see if `any` element of `S` is `%in%s`.

Answer (score 3):

## [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/), 88 bytes

```
s(A,B,C):-between(A,B,C),C<B,between(1,B,X),B+C=:=X*X.
g(X):-s(1,X,Y),s(Y,X,Z),s(Y,Z,Y).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@xCoMwEIZ3n@K6JfUU7Sg6VAdd7OSQWjq0ECRQtJiADn13ezE6lIYM9/0/95G8x@E1dIGe1LJodsYcC54ET2kmKfuNsUhz3KOYIsEx94ssycRRhF7HBK1oagReOWp2paF1Q0tJuBipDbvdEQRdHnqOq09DUYVQP2YOSeABnQpSy7hCxyqOcHBQgtJU@xA7XiUNQukEm5WCWvW/Tgo26@66yNlYnW3@hLbcnd6mWDt6fYRwiiLuFqZRGcnsh5Yv)

```
s(A, B, C) :-
    between(A, B, C), % Find an integer C between A and B (inclusive),
    C < B,            % which is less than B.
    between(1, B, X), % Find an integer X between 1 and B (inclusive),
    B+C =:= X*X.      % of which (B+C) is the square.
g(X) :-
    s(1, X, Y), % Find Y: 1 <= Y < X, and X+Y is a perfect square
    s(Y, X, Z), % Find Z: Y <= Z < X, and X+Z is a perfect square
    s(Y, Z, Y). % Make sure that Z > Y and Y+Z is a perfect square
```

`g(X)` is the rule that takes an integer as parameter and outputs whether it is a square triangle number (true/false).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
ṖŒc;€ŒcS€Æ²ẠƊ€Ẹ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmlHJyVbP2paA6SCgdThtkObHu5acKwLyH64a8f///8NzQA)

#### How?

```
ṖŒc;€ŒcS€Æ²ẠƊ€Ẹ || Full program.
                ||
Ṗ               || Popped range. Yields [1, N) ∩ ℤ.
 Œc             || Pairs (two-element combinations).
   ;€           || Append N to each.
            Ɗ€  || For each of the lists, check whether:
           Ạ    || ... All ...
       S€       || ... The sums of each of their...
     Œc         || ... Disjoint Pairs
         Æ²     || ... Are perfect squares.
              Ẹ || Test whether there is any value that satisfies the above.
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 72 bytes

Returns `0` or `1`.

```js
x=>(g=y=>z?y>z?![x+y,x+z,y+z].some(n=>n**.5%1)|g(y-1):g(x-1,z--):0)(z=x)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f=

x=>(g=y=>z?y>z?![x+y,x+z,y+z].some(n=>n**.5%1)|g(y-1):g(x-1,z--):0)(z=x)

for(n = 1; n < 150; n++) {
  f(n) && console.log(n)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 113 bytes

```c
p(n){return(int)sqrt(n)==sqrt(n);}f(x,y,z,r){for(r=y=0;++y<x;)for(z=y;++z<x;p(x+y)&p(x+z)&p(z+y)&&++r);return!r;}
```

Returns `0` if the number is square triangle, `1` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU5BCoMwEDw3r4hCJUsixHPMT3oR2xRBU7taMBG/3nTTdi6zM7vsTF/f@z6lWXjY8ba@0IvBr7A8cSXL2v9gDic2FVRUCLt7oEAbrDZShnYzkI1oA8lIchabDFBlipliVpWUCOaXUKA5EqXwqRu8ALYzTqAnPGdzbxvDfdtorQ2X0sN3nTE4LgpHdYCdsp6R7p0oz9eLLxWnmuxI796N3X1J9Th9AA)

Comment: I'm guessing the `return(int)sqrt(n)==sqrt(n)` is being parsed as `return((int)sqrt(n))==sqrt(n)` as opposed to the more obvious `return(int)(sqrt(n)==sqrt(n))`? If not can you explain what `p` is doing?

Comment: @MDXF Type cast [has higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `==`, so the expression is parsed as `((int)sqrt(n))==sqrt(n)` like you guessed.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 49 bytes

```apl
{∨/{0=+/(⍺=⍵),1|.5*⍨(⍺+⍵)(⍺+k)(⍵+k)}/¨,⍳2⍴1-⍨k←⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqRx0r9KsNbLX1NR717rJ91LtVU8ewRs9U61HvCpCINkgEzMgGUVuBVK3@oRU6j3o3Gz3q3WKoC1SXDTQHKFX7/79G2qEVQBlDAwNNfQgNAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 61 bytes

Start reading from the function `all`. The first argument is an anonymous function checking that the square root of a number is an integer, this is applied to each value in the second argument. The single argument to `any` is a `Generator` with two for loops, which for each iteration contains the output of the `all` function.

Thanks to Mr Xcoder for -2 bytes.

```julia
x->any(all(x->√x%1==0,[x+y,x+z,y+z])for y=1:x-1for z=1:y-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59mm5Sanpn3v0LXLjGvUiMxJ0cDyHzUMatC1dDW1kAnukK7UqdCu0qnUrsqVjMtv0ih0tbQqkLXEMSsAjIrdQ01/6fmpXA5FGfklyukaRgbaCLYhppcBUWZeSU5eRppmXkpGml6GkZWhgYGmpraQG0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>95</s> <s>88</s> 86 bytes

```
import StdEnv
@x#l=[1..x-1]
=or[all(\n=or[i^2==n\\i<-l])[x+y,y+z,z+x]\\y<-l,z<-l|y<>z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxCsMgFAD3fIXQpcUYYudYMqRDoVtGtSCJKcLTlMQWlX57bbIcxw03gFYu23l8g0ZWGZeNfc2LR70fr@5TtOEAjNOqCoTKgs0LVwBH4XYzjzNjTgjTEJAnHnAsI05lwkEKEbdYpg3f2FySzL1X25WhyYDXC2rRPqV1LfNvmEA910xu99xFp6wZ1j8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 73 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1...n).any?{|b|(1...b).any?{|c|[n+b,b+c,n+c].all?{|r|r**0.5%1==0}}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYu7CoAwDAB/xUVQq6EKjtUPEQdTdCpBqoKl8dvjA7ztDs4fGGQxUnUUsxoAKIeJQh8Z@XP83fJACktUtiRlR5ice6pnXxQa2rQ2Rl8Psibv12idwza72e6RT16Gc7xEbg)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
q:2XN!tG+wsvX^1\aA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v9DKKMJPscRdu7y4LCLOMCbR8f9/YwMA) Returns 1 for falsey, 0 for truthy.

Testcases up to 500: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syflvamBgpeQQ4fG/0Moowk@xxEO7vLgsIs4wJtHxf529g8t/AA) (using `H` instead of `G`). Runtime is quadratic in the input size, so enumerating the testcases from `1` to `n` runs in `O(n^3)`, which is why enumerating all testcases up to 1000 times out on TIO.

- -1 byte and a conjecture less thanks to @LuisMendo
- -1 byte by a more clever check of integer-ness.

Removing `q` generates a sequence with the desired sequence as a subset, but without the constraint that `y` and `z` be strictly smaller than `x`. An example is `x=18`, `y=7`, `z=18`.

```
q:    % Push 1...n-1
2XN   % Generate all permuations of choosing 2 numbers from the above.
!     % Transpose to take advantage of column-wise operators later on.
 G+   % Add n to these combinations, to have all combos of x+y and x+z
t  ws % Duplicate the combinations, swap to the top of the stack and sum to get y+z.
v     % Concatenate vertically. The array now contains columns of [x+y;x+z;y+z].
X^    % Element-wise square root of each element
1\    % Get remainder after division by 1.
a     % Check if any have remainders, columnwise. If so, it is not a square triangle.
A     % Check whether all combinations are not square triangle.
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. Too bad, I was hoping for an answer to my conjecture, but I can't just ask it at Math.SE without showing some effort for a proof...

Comment: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/ here you go

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 63 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
0←Đ⁻Đ`⁻Đ3ȘĐ3Ș+√ĐƖ=4ȘĐ3ȘĐ3Ș+√ĐƖ=4ȘĐ3ȘĐ3Ș+√ĐƖ=4Ș6Ș**4Ș↔+↔łŕ⁻Đłŕŕŕ
```

Tests all possible combinations of y,z such that 1≤z<y<x

Returns 1 if x is a square triangle number, 0 otherwise

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f4FHbhCMTHjXuPjIhAUwan5gBJrQfdcw6MuHYNFsTqACRomYnZmhpAelHbVO0gfho09GpYHNBDBD8/9/EBAA)